# initialize a list with 2 digit numbers

Tags: python, list

I have a list of other lists I am using to represent a map of my workspace. Here is a simplified version:

```
areaMap = [[00,00,00,00,00],[00,00,01,11,01]]
```

Now, when i print this onto the screen using:

```
for x in range(len(areaMap)):
    print(areaMap[x])
```

the leading zero will be chopped off:

```
[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,11,1]
```

I need these numbers to have 2 digits so they are visually appealing when printed. I tried using:

```
for y in areaMap:
    [str(item).zfill(6) for item in areaMap[y]]
```

but this creates unneeded quotation marks and spaces.

Comment: And that's why you don't use the built-in representation for presentation.

Comment: Can you show exactly how you want the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the format for the entirety of each line; for example

```
for x in areaMap:
    print("[%s]" % (",".join(["%02d"%z for z in x])))
```